# what is the probabilty for atleast three question with B option?

Tags: probability

A test has 5 mcq .Each question has 4 option A B C and D .What is probabilty that student will choose B option for atlest three questions if student leaves no questions blank?[image]

my attempt getting 83/512.

Comment: Any thoughts from your end?

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art ..added my answer ..but answer is wrong

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include your attempt rather than posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the students’ answers are uniformly distributed, then there are $4^5 = 1024$ total ways the student could answer, and $\binom{5}{3}3^2 = 90$ ways the student could have three B’s; the first term counts where the B’s are and the second selects the two answers that don’t have B from the three remaining choices. There are $\binom{5}{4}3^1 = 15$ ways for there to be four B’s, and only one way for there to be Thus, the answer is $(90+15+1)/1024 = 53/512$.

Comment: Well, sure. I’ll edit.

Comment: The OP is asking about 3 B's, not 3 C's. More important, he wants **at least** 3, not **exactly** 3